# Python Cutting a string to multiple variables

Tags: python, string, raspberry-pi, lcd, webiopi

Im looking for a way to "cut" a string that comes from an html input into 4 variables, depending on the length of the original string. I need to do this because i want to show the string on the RaspberryPi LCD-Display. Because the LCD can only show 20 Letters per row, i thought about putting the rest of the string into another variable.

Right now my Pythoncode looks like this.

```
def text1(text):
    global TextA
    TextA = text
    TextA = urllib.request.unquote(TextA)
    subprocess.Popen(["espeak", "-vde",  TextA])
    subprocess.Popen(["python2", "/home/pibot/display.py", TextA])
```

The Part with espeak works perfect. The display output only works if the string contains less than 20 letters.

So basically i just want to split TextA into TextA1 TextA2 TextA3 and TextA4.

I thought about doing it with

```
if len(TextA) > 20
```

but i dont really know how to get further with this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: Can the TextA be split using a delimiter (, ; or others)? Use split(). Or do you need certain parts? lookup string slicing

Comment: Use the built-in [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) library to do this. It will ensure that you don't e.g. cut a word in half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice strings like this:

```
>>> 'very long string, much longer than 20 characters'[0:20]
'very long string, mu'
```

you don't need to check if the string is longer than 20 characters, you can just always add the slicing to your subprocess statement: `TextA[0:20]` will not touch the string if it's shorter than 20 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need proper word wrapping, try a comprehension like this:

```
from math import ceil
str = 'very long string, much longer than maxLength characters.'\
      'very long string, much longer than maxLength characters'

maxLength = 20
numStringsOut = int(ceil(len(str)/float(maxLength)))

subStringList = [str[p * maxLength: p * maxLength + maxLength]
                 for p in range(numStringsOut)]
print(subStringList)
```

output:

```
['very long string, mu', 'ch longer than maxLe', 'ngth characters.very', ' long string, much l', 'onger than maxLength', ' characters']
```